# How can I fit this long equation inside MS Word content window?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, equation-editor

I am trying to write a very long equation in MS Word and for some reason my equation is going outside content window. (clicking ENTER, increasing paragraph spacing and linear mode not helping)

[Screenshot of my document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FudB0.png)

Comment: You can try to make your page landscape, or choose a bigger page size. Or try to [change the font](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/word-equation-font/m-p/3772384) But I'd guess that Word just isn't made to handle such equations. There's a reason most of the science community uses latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens, when you are typing inside a predefined equation field that looks something like this:
[image]

Everything you type into this dotted field will stay in one line in Word. So, in your case, you might want to cut the content starting with the curly bracket, then move the cursor outside of the field, press ENTER and then paste the content.